# get_value returning `f64` instead of `[u8; 4]`

Tags: rust

I'm using the `noise` crate and having trouble understanding how to convert their [`Color` type](https://github.com/Razaekel/noise-rs/blob/5d8125431dec1516fb963dd3b7a11f9e4c5f6f72/src/utils/color_gradient.rs) to an RGB value.

```
noise = "0.7.0"
```

```rust
pub type Color = [u8; 4];
```

I'm trying to use the `get_value()` function, seen here in the [docs](https://github.com/Razaekel/noise-rs/blob/5d8125431dec1516fb963dd3b7a11f9e4c5f6f72/src/utils/noise_image.rs) as:

```rust
pub fn get_value(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Color {
    let (width, height) = self.size;

    if x < width && y < height {
        self.map[x + y * width]
    } else {
        self.border_color
    }
}
```

`get_value()` is implemented for PlaneMapBuilder. So I would expect `PlaneMapBuilder::get_value(x,y)` to return something of the format `[r,g,b,a]`, but this does not happen:

```rust
extern crate noise;

use noise::{utils::*, Billow};

fn main() {
    let mut my_noise = PlaneMapBuilder::new(&Billow::new()).build();
    let my_val = my_noise.get_value(1,1);
    println!("{}", my_val.to_string());
    ///returns something like -0.610765515150546, not a [u8;4] as I would expect
}
```

In the [docs](https://github.com/Razaekel/noise-rs/blob/5d8125431dec1516fb963dd3b7a11f9e4c5f6f72/src/utils/color_gradient.rs) I see this definition of `add_gradient_point()` which takes a `Color` as a parameter:

```rust
pub fn add_gradient_point(mut self, pos: f64, color: Color) -> Self {
    // check to see if the vector already contains the input point.
    if !self
        .gradient_points
        .iter()
        .any(|&x| (x.pos - pos).abs() < std::f64::EPSILON)
    {
        // it doesn't, so find the correct position to insert the new
        // control point.
        let insertion_point = self.find_insertion_point(pos);

        // add the new control point at the correct position.
        self.gradient_points
            .insert(insertion_point, GradientPoint { pos, color });
    }

    self
}
```

Here they use the `[u8; 4]` structure I would expect for the `Color` type:

```rust
let jade_gradient = ColorGradient::new()
.clear_gradient()
    .add_gradient_point(-1.000, [24, 146, 102, 255])
    .add_gradient_point(0.000, [78, 154, 115, 255])
```

What could explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `get_value()` is implemented for `PlaneMapBuilder`

You are correct that [`PlaneMapBuilder`](https://docs.rs/noise/0.7.0/noise/utils/struct.PlaneMapBuilder.html) "implements" `get_value()`. However, it is not `get_value()` from [`NoiseImage`](https://docs.rs/noise/0.7.0/noise/utils/struct.NoiseImage.html#method.get_value). It is actually [`NoiseMap`](https://docs.rs/noise/0.7.0/noise/utils/struct.NoiseMap.html#method.get_value), where its [`get_value()`](https://docs.rs/noise/0.7.0/noise/utils/struct.NoiseMap.html#method.get_value) returns a `f64` and not `Color`.

---

Depending on what kind of "colors" you'd want, then you could instead use [`ImageRenderer`](https://docs.rs/noise/0.7.0/noise/utils/struct.ImageRenderer.html) and call its [`render()`](https://docs.rs/noise/0.7.0/noise/utils/struct.ImageRenderer.html#method.render) method with `&my_noise`, which returns a `NoiseImage`.

```rust
// noise = "0.7.0"
use noise::{utils::*, Billow};

fn main() {
    let my_noise = PlaneMapBuilder::new(&Billow::new()).build();
    let image = ImageRenderer::new().render(&my_noise);
    let my_val = image.get_value(1, 1);
    println!("{:?}", my_val);
    // Prints: `[18, 18, 18, 255]`
}
```

---

> Here they use the `[u8; 4]` structure I would expect for the `Color` type

Just to be clear, those are the same thing in this case. In short the `type` keyword allows you to define new "[type aliases](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/type-aliases.html)" for an existing types. Essentially, you'd be able to give a complex type a shorthand name. However, they are still the same type.